# Create a list of first letters from a list of words

Tags: python, django, unicode

## views.py

```
com_list = sorted(chain(git_all, alb_all, ban_all, gaa_all, pro_all, shi_all, cat_all), key=attrgetter('title'))
return render(request, 'comb_list.html', {'combined_list':com_list})
```

## comb_list.html

```
<ul>
    {% for i in combined_list %}
        <li><a href="{{i|truncatechars:1|cut:"..."}}">{{i|truncatechars:1|cut:"..."}}</li>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

But the problem is my variable com_list is a list of unicode (Bangla) words derived from various model. and `truncatechars:1` are not working on them. I tried them manually they work only with `u''` tag. I want a list of first letter from previous list.

Comment: Are you using python 2+ or 3+?

Comment: python 2+, problem solved anyway. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the truncation in your python script:

```
first_char_list = [x[0] for x in com_list if len(x)]
```

this will produce list of characters (without the `...`, you are cutting it anyway) and just pass it to `render`. this will also simplify your html (you can just use `{{i}}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it before but it was replying Category object does not support indexing.  
  
I found the error, and eventually solved it.  

I was defined my variable
  
`cat_all = [i[0] for i in Catagory.objects.all()]`  
  
instead of   

 `cat_all = [i[0] for i in Catagory.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)]`
  
Now its working. It was my first question and I was afraid that no one is going to answer. Thank You.